# Can RDkit batch convert SMILES in a csv to individual images?

Tags: rdkit

I have a list of SMILES in a csv file (about 900 of them) that I would like to convert to individual images (200 x 200). I know I can run this:

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

smiles = 'C1CC[13CH2]CC1C1CCCCC1'
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
Draw.MolToMPL(mol, size=(200, 200))
```

and get one image out at a time but all my attempts to put it into a for loop (using a list or reading in a csv) has failed.

My for loop looks like:

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from rdkit.Chem import Descriptors
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
import PIL
from PIL import Image

smiles_list = ['ClCC(=O)N1CCc2ccc(cc12)N(=O)=O', 
'ClCC(=O)N1CCc2ccc(cc12)N(=O)=O', 'ClCC(=O)Nc1nc(cs1)-c1ccco1']

mol_list = []
for smiles in smiles_list:
    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
    mol_list.append(mol)

Draw.MolToMPL(mol_list)
```

Which has been giving me error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-83978cee41c7> in <module>
     15     mol_list.append(mol)
     16 
---> 17 Draw.MolToMPL(mol_list)

~\Anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\rdkit\Chem\Draw\__init__.py in MolToMPL(mol, size, kekulize, wedgeBonds, imageType, fitImage, options, **kwargs)
    346   if kekulize:
    347     from rdkit import Chem
--> 348     mol = Chem.Mol(mol.ToBinary())
    349     Chem.Kekulize(mol)
    350 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ToBinary'
```

Does anyone know of any rdkit tricks?

Comment: "_all my attempts to put it into a for loop or list has failed_" - if you have code that isn't working, please show it... and explain *how* it fails.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my question with the bit of code I came up with and the error I'm getting.

Comment: `MolToMPL` is expecting an individual molecule, not a list of molecules, so why don't you just create another list and append the image to it within the for loop?

Comment: why don't you just add `Draw.MolToMPL(mol)` in the for loop? `Draw.MolToMPL` does not support list, it requires a single mol object.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Oliver Scott and Quat for the comments. Can get exactly what I need now! For anyone who is interested:

```
smiles_list = ['ClCC(=O)N1CCc2ccc(cc12)N(=O)=O', 'ClCC(=O)N1CCc2ccc(cc12)N(=O)=O', 
'ClCC(=O)Nc1nc(cs1)-c1ccco1']

mol_list = []
for smiles in smiles_list:
    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
    mol_list.append(mol)
    Draw.MolToMPL(mol, size=(200, 200))
```

Or simply replace smiles_list with a csv read-in:

```
smiles_list = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

mol_list = []
for smiles in smiles_list:
    for smiles in smiles_list['Smiles']:    # assuming your column is called Smiles
        mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
        mol_list.append(mol)
        Draw.MolToMPL(mol, size=(200, 200))
```